# Fedora Gnome shell menu spacing incorrect after upgrade to 24,how to fix it?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, fedora-23

I previously have fedora 23 installed, recently I use the "dnf-plugin-system-upgrade" tool upgrade to fedora 24. After upgrade everything appeared normal except gnome shell window menu spacing is narrowed and crowded. Is there anybody know how to fix this? Very grateful for your tips.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have overrides to the default CSS theme in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` ?

If so, then that might be what is causing your issue, so try removing it? (save a copy of it somewhere, first)